# Can Mautic bulk personalize emails to sent with column headers of a Google Sheet or CSV file?

Tags: mautic

I want to send out emails in large quantity/bulk that will need to be personalized for each contact based on the column headers of a Google Sheet (or a CSV file) that has all the info about each contact. Can Mautic do this?

I already searched for an answer on Google and in the tutorial docs of Mautic but with no success.